# When I try the register system I wrote in PHP(8.0) I get always the SQLSTATE[42000] 1064 error

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysql-error-1064

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''accounts' WHERE USERNAME = 'test'' at line 1 in .../phplogin/register.php:13 Stack trace: #0 .../phplogin/register.php(13): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in .../phplogin/register.php on line 13

PHP Code of register.php (username, pw and pw2 are defined in the html part):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {require("mysql.php");
        $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'accounts' WHERE USERNAME = :user");// Check username
        $stmt->bindParam(":user", $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($count == 0) {
            // Username not used
            if($_POST['pw'] == $_POST['pw2']) {
                // Create User
                $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO 'accounts' (USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (:user, :pw)");
                $stmt->bindParam(":user", $_POST['username']);
                $hash = password_hash($_POST['pw'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
                $stmt->bindParam(":pw", $hash);
                $stmt->execute();
                echo "Dein Account wurde angelegt"; // Added account into database
            } else {
                echo "Passwörter stimmen nicht überein"; // pw and pw2 are not the same
            }
        } else {
            echo "Username bereits vergeben"; // Username used already
        }
}
?>
```

I tried everythink but I can´t find out why it´s not working.
If everythink had worked fine it would create a new user with a hashed password in the database. If there were 2 users with the same name it would say that the username is already used.

Comment: Tables should be surrounded by ticks when quoted at all. Single and double quotes will tell mysql that it's a value, not a table or column name

Comment: OMG THANKS IT FINALLY WORKED!!!!